# Simultaneously improving multiple classifiers using feedback from one another

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multivariate-analysis

I am working on inferring multiple variables from a given dataset.

The data is $X = {x_1, x_2,...., x_N}$ and there are $K$ classifiers $C_1,..., C_K$. Each classifier takes $x_n$ as input and returns a categorical variable as the classification output.

However I want to be able to factor in the classification outputs from $C_{-k}$ into the classification from classifier $C_k$ (the output variables may or may not be correlated)

An example of such a scenario could be inferring various demographic attributes such as age, gender, and education levels from survey data of user's interests.

If someone could point me toward the relevant literature or methods it would be highly appreciated.